# Spark structured streaming sinks to output is delayed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

The below spark structured streaming code collects data from Kafka at every 10 seconds:

```
window($"timestamp", "10 seconds")
```

I was expecting the results to be printed on the console every 10 seconds. But, I notice the sink to the console is happening at every ~2 mins or above.
May I know what am I doing wrong?

```
def streaming(): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/Documents/ ")
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Histogram").setMaster("local[8]")
    conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false");
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

    import sqlcontext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window

    val inputDf = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "wonderful")
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .load()
    import scala.concurrent.duration._

    val personJsonDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
      .withWatermark("timestamp", "500 milliseconds")
      .groupBy(
    window($"timestamp", "10 seconds")).count()

    val consoleOutput = personJsonDf.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
      .start()
    consoleOutput.awaitTermination()
  }

object SparkExecutor {
  val spE: SparkExecutor = new SparkExecutor();
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("test")
    spE.streaming
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you might be missing the trigger definition for querying `personJsonDf` during the `writeStream`operation. The 2 minute period might be a default one (not sure).

The `groupBy` window that you have defined, will be used in the query but it does not define its periodicity.

One way to configure this could be:

```
val consoleOutput = personJsonDf.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
  .start()
```

Finally, the class `Trigger` contains some useful methods you wanna check out.

Hope it helps.